# How to re-connect to MongoDB using C++ driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb, exception, compiler-errors

I've a C++ function which saves a document to MongoDB using C++ driver. It takes connection reference as argument:

http://pastebin.com/jwRDhNWQ

When I restart MongoDB, I can see that new connection is being made.
However, conn.isFailed() remains true.

This maybe happening due to the fact that when I reconnect, I am using `conn` and not `&conn`
When I do use `&conn` as in  `&conn.connect("localhost");`, I get error message-

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

How do I fix this? i.e. modify the underlying connection so that conn.isFailed() becomes false when a new connection has been established?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with using the `&` operator or not. If you try to use `&` as you do, then it simply tries to get the address of the return value of the `connect` method. Instead, check if you are disconnecting/reconnecting properly?

Comment: yes, I can see that re-connection is successful in MongoDB logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable _autoReconnect in the mongo::DBClientConnection::DBClientConnection constructor.
http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_connection.html#a6a1a348024dd302572504b7bfb6e74a2

The variable _failed returned by the method isfailed() is not set until _check Connection is called.  _checkConnection is not called until something is sent to the database, so as an alternative, you could call the ping command before calling _isFailed.  However, the recommended fix is to enable _autoReconnect.

Comment: thank you !I will go ahead with enabling _autoReconnect in constructor