# How to auto re-connect to mongo when using mongocxx driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb, exception

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800242/how-to-re-connect-to-mongodb-using-c-driver) from 2012 says that when using `DBClientConnection`, you can enable automatic re-connection by setting a parameter in the constructor. However, I don't see any similar flag in the [docs for the latest version of mongocxx](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.1.1/classmongocxx_1_1client.html). (The [client connection options](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.1.1/classmongocxx_1_1options_1_1client.html) only relate to SSL).

Is there a way to enable auto-reconnect in mongocxx 3.x?